# Losing state inside eventHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const [page,setPage] = useState()

console.log(page) // gives "Page1" upon state update
const onValueChange = (event) => {
    console.log(page); //gives undefined upon state update
};

<Input
onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}         
/>

<SelectDropdown
onChange={() => setPage("Page1")}
value={page}
/>
```

Above code is a brief example on how I cant access the state "page" inside the function from an eventHandler, how is it possible to access the state inside `onValueChange()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could should work as it is normally. An explanation of why you getting `undefined` in `onValueChange` is that you are changing the value of the `Input` before changing `SelectDropdown`'s value, in witch case it's normal, because this line :

```
const [page,setPage] = useState()
```

sets page to undifined. You can test it here on this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-jennings-voxh29?file=/src/App.js) I just created.

Comment: Changing the value in SelectDropdown and then doing any change in Input gives undefined of page even if doing Input is done after SelectDropdown

Comment: @BitByte, I added a CodeSandbox link in my response, try it and you will see it's as I'm saying.

Comment: You're right. I had this issue happening because I was rendering this component which include these state twice, and their values were separate (oops). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change setStorageId to setPage in your SelectDropDown component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).